# how to customize and delete from a telerik radgrid filter menu with code?

Tags: c#, telerik, telerik-grid

I have Telerik RadGrid with filter menu I want to delete some records from the filter menu records like IsNull or IsEmpty and I also like to change the text for some records there.. to be specific I want to Customize my RadGrid Filter Menu by C# Code.. Can anyone help me please?

here is my RadGrid:

```
<telerik:RadGrid ID="gvErrors" runat="server" AllowFilteringByColumn="True" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" CellSpacing="0" GridLines="None" ShowGroupPanel="True">

            <ClientSettings allowdragtogroup="True">
                <Scrolling AllowScroll="True" UseStaticHeaders="True" />
            </ClientSettings>
<MasterTableView AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataKeyNames="TicketID">
<CommandItemSettings ExportToPdfText="Export to PDF"></CommandItemSettings>

<RowIndicatorColumn Visible="True" FilterControlAltText="Filter RowIndicator column">
<HeaderStyle Width="20px"></HeaderStyle>
</RowIndicatorColumn>

<ExpandCollapseColumn Visible="True" FilterControlAltText="Filter ExpandColumn column">
<HeaderStyle Width="20px"></HeaderStyle>
</ExpandCollapseColumn>

    <Columns>
        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="TicketID" DataType="System.Decimal" 
        FilterControlAltText="Filter TicketID column" HeaderText="TicketID"
           Visible="false"  ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="TicketID" UniqueName="TicketID">
        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="user_name" FilterControlAltText="Filter user_name column" HeaderText="UserName" SortExpression="user_name" UniqueName="user_name">
        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="email" FilterControlAltText="Filter email column" HeaderText="email" SortExpression="email" UniqueName="email">
        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Category" FilterControlAltText="Filter Category column" HeaderText="Category" SortExpression="Category" UniqueName="Category">
        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Title" FilterControlAltText="Filter Title column" HeaderText="Title" SortExpression="Title" UniqueName="Title">
        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="Issue" FilterControlAltText="Filter Issue column" HeaderText="Issue" SortExpression="Issue" UniqueName="Issue">
        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
        <telerik:GridDateTimeColumn DataField="TicketDate" DataType="System.DateTime" FilterControlAltText="Filter TicketDate column" HeaderText="TicketDate" SortExpression="TicketDate" UniqueName="TicketDate">
        </telerik:GridDateTimeColumn>
        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="TicketTime" DataType="System.TimeSpan" FilterControlAltText="Filter TicketTime column" HeaderText="TicketTime" SortExpression="TicketTime" UniqueName="TicketTime">
        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>

    </Columns>

<EditFormSettings>
<EditColumn FilterControlAltText="Filter EditCommandColumn column"></EditColumn>
</EditFormSettings>
</MasterTableView>

<FilterMenu EnableImageSprites="False"></FilterMenu>

        </telerik:RadGrid>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please try with the below code snippet.

```
public void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    GridFilterMenu menu = RadGrid1.FilterMenu;
    int i = 0;
    while (i < menu.Items.Count)
    {
        if (menu.Items[i].Text == "IsNull")
        {
            //Upadte Text
            menu.Items[i].Text = "your_custom_string";
        }
        else if (menu.Items[i].Text == "IsEmpty")
        {
            //Rmeove menu item
            menu.Items.RemoveAt(i);
        }

        i++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Ok this the same code I got from Telerik Site but lets say I'll make my updated text like "StartsWith A", so how I can make on click event selects items starts with A letter. can u think of something?

Comment: Please try with below link and let me know if any concern. http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/grid-custom-filter-options-with-handling.html

Comment: Look thats what i did
RadMenuItem menuItem = new RadMenuItem();
        gvErrors.FilterMenu.Items.Add(menuItem);
        menuItem.Text = "StartsWith A";
        menuItem.Value = "StartsWith A";
        menu.ItemClick += menu_ItemClick;

    void menu_ItemClick(object sender, RadMenuEventArgs e)
    {
        GridFilteringItem filterItem = gvErrors.MasterTableView.GetItems(GridItemType.FilteringItem)[0] as GridFilteringItem;
        filterItem.FireCommandEvent("Filter", new Pair(e.Item.Value, e.Item.Attributes["columnUniqueName"]));

but it doesnt work;